# Percentage of a graph with diameter less than x? In igraph and R

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

Suppose I have this graph in R (I am using igraph):

```
zach <- graph("Zachary")
```

I know how to calculate its diameter:

```
diameter(zach)
[1] 5
```

How can I calculate the size of a subgraph (or subgraphs) of *zach* with some given diameter, say 4?

For example, *zach* has 78 nodes and the longest shortest path between any two nodes is 5. Is there a way to calculate how many nodes have a longest shortest path of 4?

More generally, for any graph *g* and diameter *x* is there a way to return a subset of *g* with diameter *x*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple but not perfect solution. I have found that in Zachary Karate Club, the diameter is 13 and there are 34 nodes. According to that, I have wrote the following code. Here, I have remove the longest shortest path.

```
Mat = shortest.paths(karate,v=V(karate),to=V(karate),mode = "all")
Mat = ifelse(Mat>12,1,0)
g = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Mat,mode = "undirected")
elist = get.edgelist(g)
g2 = graph_from_edgelist(elist)
for (i in 1:vcount(g2)) {
   karate = delete.vertices(karate,V(g2)$name[i])
}
```

Now, after removing the nodes having longest shortest path between, I have found the *diameter 11* with subgraph *karate*.

Hope, you would get idea from this.

Comment: Thanks, Abdul... I like your idea to simply remove nodes where the longest shortest path is greater than some target number. To get a percentage of the original graph, I will subset it with the condition rather than remove the nodes altogether. I'll give that a try!